# TCP connection lost problems in c#

Tags: c#, sockets

In my application, I have a server listening on a port on localhost for client connection. Then I have clients running and establishes connection with the server. I used tcpListner in c# for the server and the clients were written in perl using Inet function.

The connection between clients and server were established without a problem and a message from client is received by the server. However, after about 3 to 4 seconds, the connection is lost. I use netstat -a to see if the status of the connection is still "established". The result is "Close_wait" after I use netstat command on DOS.

How can I debug this problem? Which side is causing the lost of connection?

Thanks

Edit:

```
$tx_socket = IO::Socket::INET->new( PeerAddr => '127.0.0.1', PeerPort => 9000, 
    LocalPort => 8000, Proto => 'tcp', 
    Type =>SOCK_STREAM, Reuse=>1 ) or die("$!\n"); 
die("init_tx_socket failed!\n") unless $tx_socket; print "Socket good!\n"; 
$tx_socket->autoflush(1); $tx_socket->print("Hello"); 
sleep(5); 
$tx_socket->print("World");
```

Comment: do you have a (small) code sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: It is very difficult to answer this without some more context. Does the server or client exit at some point? Roughly what are the clients doing during those 3 to 4 seconds? How does the server handle multiple sessions? Which end is complaining about the lost connection: server, client or both?

Comment: Neither end detects the lost of connection. I found out the connection is lost by using netstat command. The status of the connection is in "close_wait". 

I put a sleep function after the perl script sends out the first message. Then I send a second message. I only received the first message. The sleep function sleep the perl script for around 3 or 4 seconds.

Here the Perl script code:

Comment: $tx_socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
                                  PeerAddr  => '127.0.0.1',
                                  PeerPort  => 9000,
                                  LocalPort => 8000,
                                  Proto     => 'tcp',
      Type =>SOCK_STREAM,
      Reuse=>1
                                  ) or die("$!\n");

   die("init_tx_socket failed!\n") unless $tx_socket;
          print "Socket good!\n";
  
   $tx_socket->autoflush(1);

$tx_socket->print("Hello");
sleep(5);
$tx_socket->print("World");

Comment: Sorry about the format of the code. I just copy and paste it.

Comment: I can't post the server code because it will exceed the limit allows in the input box. But it is a tcpListner in a while(true) loop waitting to accept client connection using this code:

curTcpClient = OlivawRtrListner.AcceptTcpClient();

Then, it starts a thread to handle the messages clients send to him.

Comment: @alex: I edited your post with your code, instead of pasting your code in comments, you can edit your question.

Comment: Does the client block trying to send `"World"`?

Comment: I don't know if it is blocked? I only knows I don't see "world" in server.

Answer (score 1):

Capturing network packets with Microsoft Network Monitor or Wireshark, or use System.Net tracing.

Socket issues cannot be easily analyzed and handled without such analysis.